# Use Adapta theme for Lock Screen

Tags: themes, 17.10, gdm, gnome-shell

I have installed the Adapta theme.

I successfully enabled the Adapta Nokto them on the GDM3 Login Screen using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css gdm3.css /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/gdm3-Adapta-Nokto.css 1
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
```

This, of course, shows the Adapta Nokto theme whenever I need to log into my system.

However, if I *lock* my screen, the default gnome-shell theme is shown (`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`**`gnome-shell.css`**).

How can I make the Lock Screen use the Adapta-Nokto theme (`/usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/`**`gdm3-Adapta-Nokto.css`**)?

Note:
My system desktop theme is set to Adapta, and my gnome-shell theme (top bar and dock) is is set to Adapta-Nokto (because I am using the User Themes extenson).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use the `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file from the *Adapta-Nokto* theme.

EDIT: I updated this solution to create a link to the Adapta-Nokto `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` theme file, instead of copying it. This way, the Lock screen will always use the most recent version of the Adapta-Nokto theme, whenever it is updated.

1. Open a terminal, and change to the `gnome-shell` directory.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/
   ```
2. Backup the original `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file. The following command will only create the backup, if the current file is not a link (created using step 3).

   ```
   if ! [[ -h gnome-shell-theme.gresource ]]; then sudo mv gnome-shell-theme.gresource gnome-shell-theme.gresource.original; fi
   ```
3. Link to the Adapta-Nokto theme's `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file.

   ```
   sudo ln -frs /usr/share/themes/Adapta-Nokto/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource gnome-shell-theme.gresource
   ```
4. Reboot to enable the new Lock screen. (Just loging-out and logging-back-in is not sufficient to enable the new Lock screen, because you are repeatedly taken back to the Login screen after you enter your password).
5. Note: if the `gnome-shell-common` package is updated at a future time, you may need to execute steps 1 thru 3 again to re-enable the Adapta-Nokto Lock screen theme.

Reference: [Materia GDM Theme](https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/wiki/GDM-Theme)

Comment: Didn't work immediately for me; however, referring to the [Materia GDM theme](https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/wiki/GDM-Theme) link provided, helpfully pointed out that the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` also needs replacing (I'm on Bionic).  I used a similar technique to above (my theme is Pop), so: `cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme && mv ubuntu.css ubuntu.css.ORIG && ln -s /usr/share/themes/Pop/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css ubuntu.css`.  Followed by Alt+F2 then `rt` (reboot wasn't needed) and presto, it works!