# Use Arc Theme shell for lock screen even after login

Tags: gnome, themes, 18.04

I want to use the Arc theme across the board in Gnome.
So I currently am using the arc shell theme for the users shell. It works fine, except when I lock my computer.

I fixed the initial login by adding it to alternatives thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982627/use-adapta-theme-for-lock-screen)

However the answer doesn't appear to work for Arc as it does not appear to have a `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file. So I don't know how I would go about having the shell be consistent across the board?

This is using Ubuntu 18.04-Beta2

Comment: I don't see an answer yet, but I am keeping an eye on https://github.com/NicoHood/arc-theme/issues/98. You may want to chime in there to express your interest in this feature.